# Pandas DateTimeIndex ceil ambiguous argument

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out how to pass the 'ambiguous' argument.

From documentation:

[https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.ceil.html][1]

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2018 11:59:00', periods=3, freq='min')
rng.ceil('H')
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01 12:00:00', '2018-01-01 12:00:00',
               '2018-01-01 13:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

But if I try to pass the argument I receive the following error:

```
rng.ceil('H',ambiguous='NaT')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-209-f0e872bc569a>", line 1, in <module>
    rng.ceil('H',ambiguous='NaT')

TypeError: ceil() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ambiguous'
```

Thanks

Comment: Probably you have older pandas version. to use ambiguous you require `pandas 0.24.0` version. for more details visit https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.ceil.html

Comment: Thanks that is correct

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
rng.ceil(freq='H', ambiguous='NaT')
Out[5]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01 12:00:00', '2018-01-01 12:00:00',
           '2018-01-01 13:00:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```